# too many imports cause `pub serve` to hang

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

When I run `pub -v serve web` for my AngularDart app, `pub` always hangs here:

```
% pub -v serve web
FINE: Pub 1.25.0-dev.16.4
FINE: Loading asset environment...
FINE: Initializing barback...
FINE: Serving packages on localhost:0.
MSG : Loading source assets...
FINE: Providing sources for ordreset|lib.
FINE: Loading source assets finished (0.053s).
FINE: Provided sources.
FINE: Loading transformers...
FINE: Transformer dependencies:
    | angular: -
    | test/pub_serve: -
    | dart_to_js_script_rewriter: -
FINE: Using cached transformer snapshot.
MSG : Loading angular, test/pub_serve and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers...
FINE: Loading transformers from [angular, test/pub_serve, dart_to_js_script_rewriter]
FINE: Spawning isolate from ./.pub/transformers/transformers.snapshot.
FINE: Loading angular, test/pub_serve and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers finished (0.151s).
FINE: Transformers from angular: {group of [[BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'TemplatePlaceholderBuilder'], [ReflectionRemover], [StylesheetCompiler, BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'LibraryBuilder']]}
FINE: Transformers from test/pub_serve: {PubServe}
FINE: Transformers from dart_to_js_script_rewriter: {DartToJsScriptRewriter}
FINE: Loading transformers finished (0.649s).
FINE: Initializing barback finished (0.763s).
FINE: Loading asset environment finished (1.062s).
FINE: Providing sources for ordreset|web.
FINE: Bound "web" to localhost:8080.
MSG : Serving ordreset web on http://localhost:8080
FINE: [Fine from StylesheetCompiler]:
    | [processStylesheet] took 50 ms on ordreset|lib/src/dashboard_component.css
FINE: [Fine from StylesheetCompiler on ordreset|lib/src/dashboard_component.css]:
    | Took 0.2s (0.0s awaiting secondary inputs).
FINE: [Fine from StylesheetCompiler]:
    | [processStylesheet] took 30 ms on ordreset|web/main.css
FINE: [Fine from StylesheetCompiler on ordreset|web/main.css]:
    | Took 0.2s (0.0s awaiting secondary inputs).
FINE: [Fine from BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'TemplatePlaceholderBuilder' on ordreset|primary]:
    | Took 0.4s (0.0s awaiting secondary inputs).
FINE: [Fine from BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'LibraryBuilder' on ordreset|primary]:
    | Not yet complete after 10.0s
FINE: [Fine from BuilderTransformer: Instance of 'LibraryBuilder' on ordreset|primary]:
    | Not yet complete after 20.0s
```

I noticed that when removing all `import 'package:xml/xml.dart' as xml;` statements, that `pub serve` doesn't hang anymore then. But I did observe the same behaviour in the past, that removing all `import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';` fixed the problem as well. Hence I actually doubt that it's a problem with either the `xml` or the `angular_components` package but that the problem might be related to an import limitation of `source_gen`, similar to [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/source_gen/issues/46) from the past.

I've uploaded my AngularDart project [here](https://github.com/ben4ever-archive/ordreset). You can run `pub get` and then `pub -v serve web` yourself to see how `pub` hangs.

PS: I've emptied all AngularDart HTML template files before pushing the code to the public GitHub repo for privacy reasons but that shouldn't change the fact that `pub serve` should still succeed.

Comment: Weirdly enough, `pub upgrade` worked for me with your `pubspec.yaml`. What Dart version are you using?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer `1.25.0-dev.16.4`. But I also tried it with `1.24.2` and it didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried the dependeny-override as explained in my answer? I'm still wondering why it worked on my system (1.24.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @GünterZöchbauer pointed out in a comment of his answer, following the steps below solves the problem:

1. Remove `.pub` in your project folder.
2. Run `pub get --no-precompile` instead of a regular `pub get` to prevent precompiling which seems to cause the problem.
3. Now run `pub serve` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/thosakwe/pub_mediator ([web version is currently down :-/](https://github.com/thosakwe/pub_mediator/issues/3))

reveales

```
$ mediator
✗ Found 1 dependency conflict:
Found 2 mismatching dependencies on package:build:
  * angular requires  ^0.10.0
  * angular->build_barback requires  ^0.11.0
```

You can try to add

```
dependency_overrides:
  build: ^0.11.0
```

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/912

Comment: I just tried this with Dart version `1.24.2` and with your `dependency_overrides` but it still hangs and this time I also get an error just before the hang: `Error: AnalysisException: Cannot compute LIBRARY_ELEMENT for Instance of 'AssetBasedSource'`. It shows an actual stack trace but I cannot post it in a comment.

Comment: Ok, so it's not a problem with dependency resolution, but with precompilation. You could try to delete the `.pub` folder in your project and/or run `pub get --no-precompile`

Comment: Wow - removing `.pub`, then running `pub get --no-precompile` and then running `pub serve` actually worked?! Thanks heaps for the help! Is that a bug in a package though?

Comment: Might be a bug.